# OAuth 2 client access and grant code

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am reading the oauth 2 protocol using different links on web and its rfc (RFC 6749). After going through the links i have the following doubts:

1. Is it required for authorization server to maintain the grant code at its end after it has generated and passed the code to the client?
2. There is a scenario where 2 different clients try to get the token from the authorization server: First client gets the token after resource owner has logged and approved access. Then the second client(which is totally different from first one) tries to get the token.

   a) Should the second client be redirected and the resource owner 
       should be asked to login again or should the authorization server have 
       implementation in such a way that it detects that the resource owner has 
       logged in earlier and will not ask for username and password from resource
       owner?

   b) if answer to above question is yes, how can we handle the above 
       scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Authorization Server must keep state associated with the `code` a.o. the client identifier to which it was accessed, the redirect URI that the client used and the issuance timestamp. That typically means that the Authorization Server must maintain the `code` as a reference in to that state that is stored in the backend. One way to avoid that is to encode all information in to the `code` itself and encrypt it.
2. The Authorization Server may choose to maintain a login session or rely on an external SSO server to do that, so that the user does not need to authenticate again. But what it must to is ask the user for consent to issue a token to a particular client, for both the first and the second client. So: authentication can be implicit (SSO), consent must be explicit (since it is about a different client).

Comment: for 1). I think rfc differentiates between code and token. generating grant code is 1 time activity and is useful w.r.t security. Hence, is it the code or the token which the server should maintain?

for 2). can i conclude that different clients will have different tokens for a given resource owner?

Comment: 1) both `code` and `access_token` are subject to the reasoning I gave in 1. 2) different clients will indeed have different access tokens for a given resource owner; tokens are "scoped" so that they are issued for a specific client only